# Contacts details not displayed on iPad

Tags: ipad, ios, contacts

I'm having a problem with the Contacts app on my iPad. Basically I can't see anymore the contact details. This is what I can see on the right page:

[image]

I've rebooted my iPad, closed the app from the multitasking bar, synced etc. but it still doesn't work.

I'm wondering if the only solution is to restore my device (I would like to not have to do it..)

Comment: I've had this happen, and it was infuriating. I guessed in the end that it was to do with the **Groups** button being displayed, so I ended up killing the Contacts app and re-starting it - I'd love to know what the answer is!

Comment: @Clare Macrae What do you mean killing the Contacts app ? In my question I wrote I've killed it, by closing it from the multi-tasking bottom bar.

Comment: I meant closing it from the multi-tasking bar - sorry that didn't work for you. Can you provide more info like whether your contacts are synced, e.g. to iCloud, Outlook, some Exchange server etc?

Comment: @Clare Macrae iCloud I guess, I've enabled it for all apps.

Comment: So the only solution is to restore everything from iTunes ?

Comment: I'm not sure - I don't have any experience of syncing contacts on iCloud yet. Sorry not to have been able to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I've only been able to solve it by resetting the iPad.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix the problem by adding a dummy contact - when I saved it, the contact information was visible again. Just deleted the dummy contact afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

I have experience with iCloud and my guess is iCloud is causing the problem. If you've checked what's on iCloud (gone to your address book in the cloud) and it's complete, uncheck iCloud's Contacts checkbox on the iPad and when you set it up again, don't merge but replace what's on the iPad with what's on iCloud. I had problems when I started with iCloud and it took a few tries to get things all working together.

Comment: I see, Ive done what u wrote, but how do I replace the contacts instead of merging them? The fisrt time Ive answered I dont want to merge the contacts, and now icloud for contacts is off. if i turn it on, it asks again for merging. if i answer no, it is still off.

Comment: Also, the problem is there even if icloud is disabled. I  never see the bug fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution - works for many people (worked for me, after several weeks of frustration!): create a new user - type in a few details, then save. Hey presto, you can see the contact details on the right-hand side again!

Comment: Do you need to create a new user and create a contact in the new user's contact list? Or do you just need to create a new contact in the current contact list?